# Store image from gallery and display

Tags: javascript

I have coded a small API gallery that fetches an image from an API, but I need to know how do I store and save an image?

My codepen: https://codepen.io/aaron_1986/pen/VwdvqWB

Below is my JavaScript code that I used to create the API gallery that fetches an image from an API and displays the image on screen.

```
function get_image() {
let access_key = 'YmMDTJCtZaK6veBdER5WkjyqmgGBRyH6Bpdqt7WcrM4';
let url = `https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random  /?client_id=YmMDTJCtZaK6veBdER5WkjyqmgGBRyH6Bpdqt7WcrM4`;

let imageElement = document.querySelector('.image');

fetch(url)
.then(function(response){
    //console.log(response.json())
    return response.json();
})

.then(function(jsonData){
    imageElement.src = jsonData.urls.regular;
})

}

//// Array
let selected_images = [];

document.querySelectorAll('.large-image').forEach(function(img, idx) {
  img.src = "" + idx;
  img.addEventListener('click', function({target: src}){
    if(!selected_images.includes(src)) {
      selected_images.push(src);
    }
    console.log(selected_images);
   });

});
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to store the images on your server?

Comment: An example of what I am trying to code is this: https://daniel-gore.netmatters-scs.co.uk/array-reflection

Comment: The example you provided just uses [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to store an email and image id locally. So technically the images themselves are not stored (only the id), and because `sessionStorage` is used (instead of something like `localStorage` or actually storing anything on a server), once the page is closed the ***saved*** data is removed. Is that what you are trying to achieve as well?

Comment: Also, you should remove your API key from your example code here as it could be abused by bots or other malicious individuals.

Comment: Yes (I have to recreate the site).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a basic example on how to save an email and image using `sessionStorage` similar to the example provided by OP.

#### NOTE

OP mentioned they have to recreate the example site they provided (indicating some sort of assignment), however this example is not a full solution to that. This is only to answer the specific question asked by OP "*how do I store and save an image?*".

```
const _SaveData = () => {
  // Get elements
  let img = document.querySelector('.image'),
      email = document.querySelector('#email').value;
  
  // Validate email address format
  if(!/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email)) {
    console.log(`Invalid Email Address!`)
    return
  }
  
  // Set the new data and retrive any previously stored data
  let newData = {
    email: email,
    img: img.src
  },
      data = (sessionStorage.getItem("data")) ? JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("data")) : []
  
  // Update data
  data = [...data, newData]
  
  // Save data
  sessionStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data))
  console.log(`Data Saved!`)
}
```

As long as you add a field with the id `email` and set your **Save Data!** button's `onclick` value to `_SaveData()`, this will do the intended purpose. As far as recreating that site goes, there are additional things you will need to do (*such as validating duplicate images/emails and generating new images upon save*).